# html2canvas works correctly after wrapping it inside a setTimeout callback, why and what's the perfect solution for this?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am playing with `html2canvas` and I figured out it's rendering my DOM incorrectly.

I tried to Google but only see some information about putting html2canvas inside a setTimeout callback like this:

```
var delay = 1000;
$('#image').css('width', 64);
// if I stopped running the following code, the image is correctly rendered.
setTimeout(function(){
  html2canvas($("#h2cwrap")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
    showImage64(canvas.toDataURL());
  });
},delay)
```

I noticed that even changing the `var delay = 1000` setting would lead to different results. For example, if it's set to `var delay = 1`, then the image would be resized correctly but aligned wrongly. If it's set to `var delay = 1000`, the image would be resized and aligned both correctly.

How do I make sure `html2canvas` renders exactly what I see without using such weird hacks?

Comment: Can you set up a live example? [Here I tried to make one](https://jsfiddle.net/q9x5sbdw/), but I can't repro your issue.

Comment: @Kaiido 99.9999% it tries to make use of not yet loaded resources/elements. Didn't have time to find that dupe now, so if you do, then probably we should close it.

Comment: @LGSon what do you mean? What resources? For images, it will reload it entirely and should definitely wait for it to load. I never heard of such a 99.9999% of anything, sorry.

Comment: @LGSon I mean in the specific case of the current subject matter: "html2canvas having a ratio of ~100% doing <anything>". => me never heard about that, so finding a dupe... And indeed I may have misunderstood your first comment, but your second one doesn't help me see clearer. Are you really saying that it will almost always try to use a resource that is not yet loaded, that it's a known issue and that niklasvh never tried to make anything about it? That sounds... quite improbable, and even more when I use this library quite regularly and never faced such a behavior myself.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` could be there to wait for the browser to load all resources including your image and styles.

You could alternatively listen for the `load` event which will fire after all resources are loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    // All resources in document loaded and parsed
    console.log('page is fully loaded');

    html2canvas($("#h2cwrap")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
      showImage64(canvas.toDataURL());
    });

});
```